# Make a value appear in an input text with Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web

I basically have this layout:

> [user_input]
>
> [button]
>
> [output]

With the following flask code:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upperCaseIt():
   theirText = str(request.form['user_input'])
   myText = theirText.upper()
   #??? request.form['output'] = myText
   return render_template("index.html")
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
<form action="uppercasify" method="post">
   <p>Enter text</p>
   <input type="text" name="user_input">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Uppercasify" id="up">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="output" readonly>
```

All I want is to take the text the user put in user_input (which I do successfully), turn it all to uppercase and then feed back the uppercase version to the input text "output" (set to readonly so it can't be edited).

Everything is working fine, except for displaying the uppercase text into the input text "output".

Answer (score 0):

this is what jinja is for, when you do render template, it's actually using the html file as a template. If you put `{{ response }}` in the html, then when you do `render_template` you can pass in a value for response and it will fill it in on the template before sending it. I believe you set the variable by doing
`return render_template("index.html", response = whateverStringYouWant)`